# What causes the overactivity of keratin production and expression in the cells of the nail bed/ nail matrix after some traumata?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, biochemistry, molecular-biology, cell-biology

What is the cellular mechanism of traumatic(sterile) onychodystrophy(hypertrophy)? I.e one hits his toenail and has it removed twice( once after the first trauma and then again 3 years after the first removal) by a surgeon, because it got crooked and grows back dystrophic(extremely thick and dark) without any signs of infection.

Comment: Could it be an explanation that elements of the cytoskeleton extend even deeply into the nuclei of some cells and directly, mechanically influence DNA transcription. I think the mechanism is shifting proteins of the chromatin to expose genes to RNA polymerase. If this happens in cells of the nail matrix, it could explain accelerated production of keratin in response to mechanical stress.